# How can I set ID attribute for drupal 7 form elements?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi

I want to set the `ID` attribute of an element of a form that I'm creating in a module using the form API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//Here is an example 

$form['name'] = array(
 '#type' => 'item',
 '#title' => t('Title'),
 '#attributes' => array(
    'id' => 'your-id',
 ),
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`#id` property](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#id):

```
$form['foo'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Bar'),
  '#id' => 'baz',
);
```

To ensure uniqueness you should probably use [`drupal_html_id()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_html_id/7) on the ID string.